# Sampling pairs of elements from a vector but without duplication

Tags: r

Say I have a even-length vector such as this:

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7)
```

It is 14 elements long. I wish to randomly sample 7 pairs of elements without replacement, but a rule is that no pair should contain two of the same item.

So the following result would be acceptable:

```
1-2, 1-2, 1-2, 1-3, 3-4, 3-5, 6-7
```

I am not sure how to do this systematically.  Clearly brute force would work, e.g.

```
set.seed(1)
v=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7)
length(v)
v1<-sample(v)
pairs <- split(v1, ceiling(seq_along(v1)/2))
sapply(pairs, diff)

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 1  1  2  3 -6 -3  3
```

This shows that no pair has duplicate elements as the difference is always not 0. In my case, I need to do this 1000s of times and it's not so easy to avoid duplicates.  Is there a more effective way?

Comment: That only would give me one pair. I need all 14 elements to form 7 pairs where no pair has the same element twice.

Comment: Does `unique(v)` break your assumption of frequency? That is, are you expecting sampling to return a `1` four times as much as a `7`?

Comment: @r2evans yes, the returned set of pairs need to have the same frequency of each element as the original vector.  That is why `replicate(7,sample(unique(v),2))` doesn't work - because it is with replacement sampling.  I need to sample without replacement.

Comment: It seems that you don't want a random sample so much as a constrained random partition

Comment: Try `v1 <- setNames(v, make.unique(as.character(v)));
lst <- Filter(Negate(is.null), combn(names(v1), 2, FUN = function(x) if(v1[x[1]]  != v1[x[2]]) paste(v1[x], collapse='-') else list(NULL)));
sample(lst, 7)`

Comment: @RyanD that solution returns pairs that contain duplicate elements

Comment: @akrun thanks - but this solution doesn't seem to return the correct frequency of each of the original elements of `v`  e.g. sometimes a 7 will be in one of the pairs, sometimes it won't.

Comment: @JohnColeman - thanks - I wasn't sure what to term it.

Comment: Do you distinguish between the pairs 1-2 and 2-1? You could model it as one of constructing random graphs where the vertices are `unique(v)` and the counts of each element in `v` is the degree of those elements in the resulting graph (or digraph if order matters).

Comment: Do you need to the 7 pairs to match the exact frequencies which occur in the original vector, or are you trying to (on average) match their probability distribution? Those are two different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v0 <- table(v)
set.seed(2)
out <- replicate(7, sample(names(v0), size=2, prob=v0))
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,] "1"  "2"  "4"  "1"  "3"  "2"  "6" 
# [2,] "5"  "1"  "7"  "7"  "2"  "1"  "1"
```

I use `table(v)` and `names(v0)` so that I'm guaranteed the names and the probs are in the same order. (I didn't want to assume that your actual data is structured identically.) If you need integers, then it's easy enough to us `as.integer`.

If you literally need `1-2`, then

```
apply(out, 2, paste, collapse="-")
# [1] "1-5" "2-1" "4-7" "1-7" "3-2" "2-1" "6-1"
```

I'm confident that this will produce no dupes (because `names(v0)` is unique and the default `replace=FALSE`), but here's an empirical test:

```
set.seed(3)
l <- replicate(1e5, sample(unique(v), size=2, prob=table(v)))
any(l[1,] == l[2,])
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Since your solution involves `7` selected twice, it isn't a sample without replacement.

Comment: It's not 7 selected twice, it's a sample of `v0` selected twice without replacement, then repeated 7 times. There might be duplicates between the seven *pairs*, but no duplicates within any one pair. (I think it's safe to say "never duplicates within the pairs" based on the assumption that `sample(..., replace=FALSE)` is correct.) Are you thinking instead of `replicate(2, sample(v0, size=7, replace=TRUE))`?

Comment: Perhaps OP needs to clarify. My reading of it is that they want to take those 14 elements and arrange them into 7 pairs in such a way that no pair contains a duplicate. If so, your solution doesn't satisfy that. They seem to have an exact frequency of 1, 2, etc. in mind as opposed to a distribution which is weighted in a certain way. If my reading is correct, I don't see an easy solution.

Comment: There may certainly be *identical pairs* (`1e5 - 7*6` in my extreme example), but never any duplicates within a single pair. Perhaps it will help to clarify: I'm saying I will *never* see `1-1`, though I am likely to get `c("1-2", "1-2")`.

Comment: Do you agree that `sample(names(v0), size=2)` will *never* produce duplicates?

Comment: I don't disagree, but that isn't the point. Your collection of 7 pairs has 5 1's, 3 2's, one each of 3,4,5,6, and 2 7's OP seems to want 4 1's, 3 2's, 3 3's, and one each of 4,5,6,7. He is looking for a partition of 14 elements into 7 2-element cells, where no cell contains a duplicate.

Comment: Ahhh, I see ... I was assuming random sampling, you're talking all randomized combinations (with constraints). I guess I was putting too much stock in the OP's phrasing: *randomly sample 7 pairs*. We'll see when jalapic returns.

Comment: Perhaps it was a bit of an XY problem and you solved the question OP should have asked (+1), though I find it puzzling that in the comments OP rejected one solution because it had the property that "sometimes a 7 will be in one of the pairs, sometimes it won't" but then turned out to be happy with a solution that has that very property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of your "brute-force" approach (better known as "hit-or-miss"):

```
rand.pairs <- function(v, time.out = 1000){
  n <- length(v)
  for(i in 1:time.out){
    v <- sample(v)
    first <- v[1:(n/2)]
    second <- v[(n/2+1):n]
    if(all(first != second)) return(unname(rbind(first,second)))
  }
  NULL
}
```

The point of `time.out` is to avoid infinite loops. For some input vectors a solution might be either impossible or too hard to hit upon by chance.

Example run:

```
> v <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7)
> set.seed(1234)
> rand.pairs(v)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    6    3    3    7    2    2    5
[2,]    1    4    1    1    3    1    2
```

It is fast enough to run thousands of times:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(rand.pairs(v))
Unit: microseconds
          expr min    lq     mean median     uq    max neval
 rand.pairs(v) 6.7 7.758 16.17517 12.166 19.747 70.877   100
```

Your mileage may vary, but if your machine is at all comparable, you should be able to call this function over 50,000 times per second. `replicate(10000,rand.pairs(v))` takes much less than a second to run. On the other hand, if you have an input for which the constraints are harder to satisfy, a solution might require more time.